# Extraction of RNA from algae

Tags: plant-physiology, rna, lab-techniques

I have used a standard protocol (I will give the bibliography below) to extract RNA from an algae (Posidonia) but I have get literally nothing, since I could not even see traces of the two rRNA. I think that I have failed because the huge quantity of salt and/or carbohydrates in algae in comparison with terrestrial plants. My final objective is to get mRNA and then sequence it, so I need a very good extraction.
Any ideas of paper I could read to go above this problem?
Gambino, G., Perrone, I., & Gribaudo, I. (2008). A rapid and effective method for RNA extraction from different tissues of grapevine and other woody plants.Phytochemical Analysis, 19(6), 520-525.